# Accessing attributes of Python object in an object in a list

Tags: python, list, class, object, oop

I am very new to Python and OOP so if there is any additional info I missed or errors in my code/logic I am hopeful for helpful criticism.

I have an object in the location class initialized as such:

```
class Location:
   def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

location1 = Location(0,0)
location2 = Location(1,1)
```

This object is then passed as an attribute into a class called Passenger and a class called Car, which are both initialized as such:

```
class Passenger:
    def __init__(self, passenger_name, location):
        self.passenger_name = passenger_name
        self.location = location

passenger1 = Passenger("John Doe", location1)

class Car:
    def __init__(self, car_name, location, cost_per_mile):
        self.car_name = car_name
        self.location = location
        self.cost_per_mile = cost_per_mile

car1 = Car("car1", location2, 0.5)
```

Then finally, I have a class initialized into the variable "mobileApp"

```
class CarSharingApp:
    cars = []
    passengers = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add_car(self,car):
        CarSharingApp.cars.append(car)
        print(f"Car successfully added.")

    def add_passenger(self, passenger):
        CarSharingApp.passengers.append(passenger)
        print(f"Passenger successfully added.")

mobileApp = CarSharingApp()
mobileApp.add_car(car1)
mobileApp.add_passenger(passenger1)
```

that holds a list of these passenger and car objects (which still both hold the Location objects inside them) as CLASS attributes rather than an instance attribute in a list naturally named "passengers" and "cars". My QUESTION is how can I now access the (x,y) coordinates of these car and passenger objects in order to use them in an equation? I need to essentially find the distance between cars and passengers.I know how to access the list itself, but not the location objects x and y attributes nested in the list of objects.

Comment: You can just access them like you would any other object attribute. For example: `CarSharingApp.cars[0].location.x` to get the `x` value for the first (index `0`) car. Also, you should rethink `CarSharingApp`. Storing the passengers and cars as class members defeats a lot of the purpose of using a class. And also, if you don't need an `__init__`, you don't need to add a definition at all. It's not necessary to add one with a `pass` body.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I wanted to but I embarrassingly could not figure out how to do so without taking any input in the object initialization. I need the class to initialize with no input. the class then has about 7 methods that handle various tasks. I am going to implement you solution now and see.

Comment: Why are you using class attributes in the first place? Even if you are only instantiating `CarSharingApp` once, there's no reason to make it behave differently than if you had two instances that, presumably, would have distinct lists of cars and passengers.

Comment: @chepner because as stated, I am new to OOP, any helpful criticism or tips on how to use lists as instance variables would be helpful. Otherwise for the purposes of this, the class variables are functional.

Comment: It's no different from using a value of any other type as an instance attribute, as you do in `Location`, `Car`, and `Passenger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are modifying the CarSharingApp.cars and not self.cars, so the cars will be appended to CarSharingApp.cars instead of mobileApp.cars

CarSharingApp.cars is a list containing car objects.
CarSharingApp.cars[0] accesses the first car, CarSharingApp.cars[0].location accesses the location object of the first car
And CarSharingApp.cars[0].location.x accesses its x coordinate

```
x_coordinate_of_first_car  = CarSharingApp.cars[0].location.x
y_coordinate_of_first_car = CarSharingApp.cars[0].location.y
# similarly
x_coordinate_of_first_passenger = CarSharingApp.passengers[0].location.x
y_coordinate_of_first_passenger = CarSharingApp.passengers[0].location.y
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah this worked for Cars but not for Passengers as it “does not have attribute “location”. So now I’ve gotta sort that out.

Comment: It will work for passengers as well, make sure there isn't any typo, you made those two classes and inserted them in the list in the same way, so it will work for both @user159